# MVC4 app not connecting to SQL Server when run on local machine

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 app that was working before I started working on it today. As far as I know I did not make any changes to the connection strings.

I have a connection string set to use a SQL Server 2012 database.

When trying to run the app from my local machine I get this error:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*
>
> *Description:*
>
> *An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*
>
> *SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:*
>
> *The connection string specifies a local SQL Server Express instance using a database   location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully check for existence of the application services database and automatically create the application services database:*
>
> *Sql Server Express must be installed on the machine.*

If I run the app from the server that it resides on I do not get this error. I can also access the SQL Server database from both my local machine and the server with SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studios built in Server Explorer.

Comment: Have you tried check all parameters described in the error message? Are you sure that not any firewall is blocking?

Comment: I am sure. The firewall is wide open for the SQL server port. I tried to get teh app to not create the local instance by putting `<remove name="LocalSQLserver"/>` in the web.config.

Comment: I found the problem, but I still dont know how to fix it. I will post in another question.